# Swift bridging header not exporting React Native types

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, bridging-header

I'm trying to create a native (iOS) module for a React Native app using Swift. I want to expose a method on the module that returns a promise, using functions of type `RCTPromiseResolveBlock` and `RCTPromiseRejectBlock`, both of which are declared in React Native's `RCTBridgeModule.h` header. However, my build fails with the message "Use of undeclared type..." for both of these types.

I had already created a bridging header (automatically using Xcode) for another purpose, so I believe importing `React/RCTBridgeModule.h` is all that I'd need to supply the types mentioned above. Presumably I've misconfigured something, as this doesn't fix the issue. I've tried setting up a fresh project and everything works as expected there, but I can't seem to find a difference that would cause my project's build to fail.

Some relevant configuration details:

- Bridging header named `<ProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h` and stored in my source directory. I moved it around to confirm that Xcode is finding it (the build fails differently when it's not in the right place).
- The contents of the bridging header is simply: `#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>`
- In my project build settings:

  - `<ProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h` is configured as the "Objective-C Bridging Header"
  - "Install Objective-C Compatibility Header" is set to "Yes"
  - "Precompile Bridging Header" is set to "Yes"
- When I type alias the missing types the project builds and runs as expected
- I have some third-party Swift libraries installed (one using `react-native link` and one using a Git submodule)
- I've tried cleaning the build folder, reinstalling `node_modules` and deleting Xcode derived data, all to no effect.

Is my project misconfigured or have I otherwise missed something important?

Answer (score 7):

This tutorial is pretty good at explaining how to set up a native module using Swift. It breaks everything down into steps and it is quite easy to follow.

https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-1-modules-9bb8d054db03

1. Setup
2. How to expose a Swift class to JS
3. How to expose static Swift data
4. How to expose a Swift method
5. How to expose a method with a callback
6. **How to expose a method as a Promise**
7. How to expose an Event Emitter
8. How to extract your React Native Module

Clearly it is step 6 that you are looking to do.

Here is a code example. It is very similar to what is done in the above link. Your bridging header should look like this:

```
// <ProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h

#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
```

---

You should have files named `ModuleName.m` and `ModuleName.swift`.

```
// ModuleName.m
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ModuleName, NSObject)
// this is how we expose the promise to the javascript side.
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(functionWithPromise: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter: (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
@end
```

---

```
// ModuleName.swift

@objc(ModuleName)
class ModuleName: NSObject {
  @objc
  func constantsToExport() -> [AnyHashable : Any]! {
    return ["projectName": "ModuleName"]
  }

  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  @objc
  func functionWithPromise(
    _ resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
    rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock
  ) -> Void {
    if (//something bad happens) {
      let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 200, userInfo: nil)
      reject("ERROR_FOUND", "failure", error)
    } else {
      resolve("success")
    }
  }
}
```

---

Then on the Javascript side you can access it like this:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

NativeModules.Counter.functionWithPromise()
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.log(e.message, e.code))
```

Comment: While that is a great tutorial (thanks for posting), it didn't fix my issue. As far as I can tell, I've set everything up as the tutorial described; I have a sneaking suspicion I broke something in my build settings, but I'm not sure what. I've been hoping there's a way to delete the bridging header and have Xcode regenerate it for me, but I haven't been able to make that happen. Also, for what it's worth `RCTEventEmitter.h` is only necessary if you're coding up an event emitter in swift; `RCTBridgeModule.h` has the promise symbols.

Comment: @Andrew How to resolve a HKStatisticsQuery?? I need to read the query in my JS file. I tried your above method to access it in my JS file but it didn't work. Any inputs?

Comment: @grooot I don’t do much with React-Native anymore so I cannot answer your question. I would suggest writing up your question and posting it properly on SO. You may find someone who is able to help you with it. Good luck.